# Handling redirects when updating model via model form with 2 views and ajax

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using ajax and two views. Everything works fine except I cannot figure out how to best handle redirect. Obviously it's redundant to render the form twice on one page and then another. How can I update my model without redirecting the user?

forms.py

```
class RecruitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    jobnum = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['jobnum','rec_count']
```

view.py

```
def recruiting(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    recruit_form = RecruitForm(request.POST or None)
    if recruit_form.is_valid():
      t = Job.objects.get(jobnum=recruit_form.cleaned_data.get('jobnum'))
      t.jobnum = recruit_form.cleaned_data.get('jobnum')
      t.rec_count = recruit_form.cleaned_data.get('rec_count')
      t.save()

def edit(request): #testing

  jobnum = request.GET.get('jobnum')
  job_list = Job.objects.filter(jobnum=jobnum)
  json_data = serializers.serialize('json', job_list)
  a = json.loads(json_data)
  a = a[0]['pk']
  j = Job.objects.get(pk=a) 
  form = RecruitForm(request.POST or None ,instance=j)
  instance = form.save(commit=False)
  instance.save()



  return render(request, "editrec.html", {"form":form})
```

javascript.js

```
$('.row2').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).data('jobnum')
    $.ajax({
    url: "/edit/",
    data: {'jobnum':a},
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data)
        $(".divtest").html(data);

        document.getElementById('editform').action='../edit/?jobnum=' + encodeURIComponent(a);    
    },
    });
});
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^edit/$','SiteTwo.views.edit', name='edit'), #testing
```

editrec.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <form method='POST' id='editform' action = '' class='givemewhite'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button class = 'btn btn-default' name='edit'/>Submit</button>
    </form> 

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class RecruitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    jobnum = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['rec_count']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you do not like the fact that the user navigates to a new page when submitting the form loaded via AJAX. To prevent that from happening, you have to trap the `'submit'` event in the loaded form. You might change your `javascript.js` to something like:

```
$('.row2').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).data('jobnum')
    $.ajax({
    url: "/edit/",
    data: {'jobnum':a},
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data)
        var form = jQuery(".divtest").html(data).find('#editform');
        form.attr('action', '../edit/?jobnum=' + encodeURIComponent(a));
        form.submit(function () {
            jQuery.ajax(form.attr('action'), {
                data: form.serialize(),
                method: form.attr('method').toUpperCase(),
                success: function () {
                    /* Reload the containing document to show new data. */
                    document.location.reload();
                }
            });
            /* Disable propagation and prevent default action (browser navigates to new page and submits). */
            return false;
        });
    },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def recruiting(request):
   # Create custom form to use here, taking only one input that is job that you want to change. you can use modelchoicefield for list.


def edit(request): #testing

     jobnum = request.GET.get('jobnum')
     job_list = Job.objects.filter(jobnum=jobnum)
     json_data = serializers.serialize('json', job_list)
     a = json.loads(json_data)
     a = a[0]['pk']
     j = Job.objects.get(pk=a) 
     form = RecruitForm(request.POST or None ,instance=j)
     if request.POST:
         if form.is_valid():
              form.save()

     return render(request, "editrec.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: How does the 'something' portion work? How does django know what job number the user selected via the `modelchoicefield`?

Comment: the 'something' is provided by the system before the page loads and not by the user. Are you trying to change job related details and the selection of that particular job on the same page?

Comment: Yes, I have a form that is already loaded on the page with all of the job options, the user will select the job they want to update, and then update it.

Comment: you cannot do it like this, either separate this into 2 view methods and use AJAX or create a custom form not modelform (but you won't be able to show previous data in form).

Comment: Ok, i've made a go at the 2 view AJAX method. Current code grabs the model data, populates the form on the page, then when I submit, it forwards me to the api'ish type page and even from there I cannot submit. Both fields have * over them but no text explaining why it won't submit.  Post updated.

Comment: found out why my form wouldn't submit. Not sure how to handle redirects